# Libreoffice pipe communication does not work when launched from Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, libreoffice

I am trying to develop Libreoffice Calc python macros in Pycharm. I want to run test inside Pycharm. Tests work fine when libreoffice is launched outside Pycharm but fail when I try to launch it directly from inside Pycharm.

I tried 2 different options for launching libreoffice.

From my ubuntu terminal

```
/opt/libreoffice6.4/program/soffice --calc --accept="pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" --nologo&
```

With a python function :

```
args = ["/opt/libreoffice6.4/program/soffice", "--calc",
        "--accept=\"pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager\""]
subprocess.Popen(args, universal_newlines=True)
```

The following code gives me the active sheet.

```
def current_active_sheet():
    localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
    resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
    ctx = resolver.resolve("uno:pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
    desktop = ctx.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)
    model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
    return model.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
```

When Libreoffice is launched from the ubuntu terminal, the `current_active_sheet` function works perfectly fine inside Pycharm, called from test modules for example. But when Libreoffice is launched from Pycharm with the python `subprocess.Popen`, the function raises a connection exception, although libreoffice is running correctly.

I have tried that both with socket and pipe options for uno bridge and get the same behaviour.

The `lsof` traces give something strange as if pycharm was not conveying the pipe name to the system.

Here is an extract of the `lsof` result when libreoffice is launched from ubuntu terminal, there is a reference to `lopipe`

```
soffice.b 13506 13517             yves    7u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0     336561 /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_6e6e1dcdf8a8f89eb21d8fe15230aa95 type=STREAM
soffice.b 13506 13517             yves   54u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0     310587 /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_lopipe type=STREAM
```

And the same extract when Libreoffice is launched from within Pycharm with the `subprocess.Popen`. No lopipe at all...

```
soffice.b 13407 13418             yves    7u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0     307196 /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_6e6e1dcdf8a8f89eb21d8fe15230aa95 type=STREAM
soffice.b 13407 13419             yves    7u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0     307196 /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_6e6e1dcdf8a8f89eb21d8fe15230aa95 type=STREAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a rather simple error. When you launch inside the python script, you should not include the quote in the `args`. It was a mistake induced by the way you need to launch it in windows command line.

So here are the correct ways to launch the LO calc instance you want to interact with:

From Ubuntu command line :

```
/opt/libreoffice6.4/program/soffice --calc --accept="pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

From Windows Git bash terminal:

```
/c/Program\ Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice.exe --calc --accept="pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

Inside a python script:

```python
pipestring = "--accept=pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
args = [LOLAUNCHPATH, "--calc", pipestring]
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

You can then access to this instance in a python :

```python
UNOURL = "uno:pipe,name=lopipe;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext"
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
            "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
ctx = resolver.resolve(UNOURL)
```

A few additionnal comments :

- the use of `time.sleep` recommended by @Jim K is very valid before actually doing things on the instance you launch
- The hardcoded `lopipe` name should be changed to something unique, using the `uuid` package is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

If launching in a subprocess, include a time delay such as `time.sleep()` so that LO has a few seconds to start before executing API code. This is not needed when starting from a terminal because launching sequentially allows time for LO to start. Normally I would recommend launching LO from a terminal, although it should be possible to launch with a subprocess.

Also, I have had better success connecting with sockets rather than with pipes. Not sure about PyCharm specifically; I have used it with the UNO API before but not with a subprocess.

Finally, try the following links. Both require a lot of reading but seem to have good information.

- https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros/Python_Design_Guide
- ["Java LibreOffice Programming" chapter 2 (PDF)](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jlop/chaps/02.%20Starting%20and%20Stopping.pdf)

What you are trying to do with PyCharm has often been done with Java IDEs, so there should be various examples of that online.

Comment: I had tried the `time.sleep()` it does not help here. sockets or pipe give the same (bad result...) I will take a look at the links givent